# Get Pending tickets backlog count until previous date

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have table like this

```
Ticket Date  |Total Tickets Created | Pending Tickets 
------------------------------------------------------
01-04-2021   |5000                  | 200 
02-04-2021   |2000                  | 100 
03-04-2021   |3000                  | 300
```

```
   select t.created_date,t.source,t.ticket_type,
   count(*) as Total_Tickets_Created,
   sum(case when tch.before='Pending Credential' then 1 else 0 end) as Pending_Tickets,
        from r4e_mongo.mongo_repbiz_tickets t
        join r4e_mongo.mongo_repbiz_ticket_changelog tch on t.id=cast(tch.ticket_id as string)
```

I want to get Pending Tickets Backlog until the previous day like below to create a report in google data studio with date filter.

```
Ticket Date  |Total Tickets Created | Pending Tickets | Pending Tickets Backlog
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-04-2021   |5000                  | 200             |    1000
02-04-2021   |2000                  | 100             |    1100 --(1000+100)
03-04-2021   |3000                  | 300             |    1400 --(1100+300)
```

For example...i have selected October 15th date in report...it should show pending tickets backlog count until October 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sum` as a window function:

```
with mytable as (
  select date '2021-04-01' as ticket_date, 5000 as total, 200 as pending union all
  select date '2021-04-02', 2000, 100 union all  
  select date '2021-04-03', 3000, 300
)
select 
  *,
  sum(pending) over (order by ticket_date) as backlog
from mytable
```

[image]

Comment: the query works but it shows Oct 14& 15 data if I select 14th,do I have to change the timezone ?

Comment: Probably some issues with Data Studio report configuration